# Create pandas dataframe from csv rows in string or list format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I convert some data into a csv string like format row by row for example the rows look like:

## string format

1st row: **"A,B,R,K,S,E"**

2nd row: **"B,C,S,E,G,Q,W,R,W"**   # sometimes longer rows

3rd row: **"A,E,R,E,S"**         # sometimes shorter rows

## or list format

1st row: **['A','B','R','K','S','E']**

2nd row: **['B','C','S','E','G','Q','W','R','W']**

3rd row: **['A','E','R','E','S']**

I can also add \n at the end of each row.
I want to create a pandas dataframe from these rows but not sure how.
Normally I just save this data into a .csv file then I do pd.read_csv but I want to skip that step.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you add your code to question?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

First_row=['A','B','R','K','S','E']
Second_row=['B','C','S','E','G','Q','W','R','W']
Third_row=['A','E','R','E','S']
df=pd.DataFrame({'1st row':pd.Series(First_row),'2nd row':pd.Series(Second_row),'3rd row':pd.Series(Third_row)})
answer=df.T
answer

         0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1st row  A  B   R   K   S   E   NaN NaN NaN
2nd row  B  C   S   E   G   Q   W   R   W
3rd row  A  E   R   E   S   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: First I am looping and creating rows and there are many of them, how can I work with that? Secondly, I don't care about naming the rows, they can be 0,1,2,3..

Comment: Can you please share the code that you are using for creating rows

Answer (score 0):

Method - 1 : From List

Take 2D list and append it. Else, it would add the values in columns.

[image]

[image]

Method - 2 : From String

[image]